# Errno 101 Network is unreachable

Tags: python, error-handling

Suddenly I get the following error from my code, sometime ago it was running just fine. Is it caused by the internet connection?

```
 #Get data checkpoint size
url = 'http://url:8080/vrio/blk'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()



def counterVolume_one():
  wanted = {'Bytes_Written', 'Bytes_Written', 'IO_Operation'}
  for d in data['Block Devices'].itervalues():
    values = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in wanted}
    print json.dumps(values)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hyper.py", line 31, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='http://url', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /vrio/blk (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: That code will not run. Please post the exact code that causes the error. Also, a Network Unreachable usually point to network problem or a bad hostname.

Comment: This is the complete code, actually the first three lines are producing the error the next part of code I could not test because I cannot get to the network

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a timeout at the requests block ie;

`r = requests.get(url, timeout=20)`

By doing this you must most probably get rid off that error :)